# How can i write this Function with Ifs to have corresponding else statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please how can I write this Function with Ifs to have a corresponding else statement.

What I'm trying to do is to add an else statement for each of the if statement

Please see my code below.

```js
validate = (lname, fname, email, eid) => {
    if (lname) {
        this.setState({
            validationState: {
                ...this.state.validationState,
                lastname: false,
            },
        });
    }
    if (fname) {
        this.setState({
            validationState: {
                ...this.state.validationState,
                firstname: false,
            },
        });
    }
    if (helpers.isEmail(email)) {
        this.setState({
            validationState: {
                ...this.state.validationState,
                email: false,
            },
        });
    }
    if (eid) {
        this.setState({
            validationState: {
                ...this.state.validationState,
                eid: false,
            },
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean in 'shouldn't affect the other'? Can you explain, please?

Comment: i mean each if statement should have a corresponding else statement that is independent of the other

Comment: You want an `else` block where `fname` has no value?

Comment: independent sounds like: if (lname) {} else {}, if (fname) {} else {}, etc. But I am sure you don't mean that...

Comment: you should use, if(first condition){Do something}else if(second condition){Do something}else if {(third contidtion){Do something}else(if no condition is met){Do something}

Comment: @Yossi exactly. the  challenge that i am having is the else for fname is affecting lname.

Comment: so my current approach won't work? or can i use a switch statement to do this?

Comment: @jasonscript yes and the else statement for fname shouldn't be independent of lname

Answer (score 0):

In the following, lname is checked, either the if clause or the else clause are executed, then, regardless of what happened until now, fname is checked, etc.
Is that what you were looking for?

```
validate = (lname, fname, email, eid) => {
  if (lname) {
    this.setState({
        validationState: {
            ...this.state.validationState,
            lastname: false,
        },
    });
  } else {
  ....
  }

  if (fname) {
    this.setState({
        validationState: {
            ...this.state.validationState,
            firstname: false,
        },
    });
  } else {
  ....
  }

  if (helpers.isEmail(email)) {
    this.setState({
        validationState: {
            ...this.state.validationState,
            email: false,
        },
    });
  } else {
  ...
  }

  if (eid) {
    this.setState({
        validationState: {
            ...this.state.validationState,
            eid: false,
        },
    });
  } else {
  ...
  }
```

}